# Probability of a finite union of non-disjoint events derivation

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

Using only the axioms of probability, derive the following result using induction:

\begin{align}
\Pr\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i\right) = &\sum_{i=1}^\infty P(A_i) - \sum_{i<j}^\infty \Pr(A_i \cap A_j) -  \\
    &\sum_{i <j<k}^\infty \Pr(A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k) - \cdots -  \\
    &(-1)^{n+1}\Pr(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap \cdots \cap A_n)  
\end{align}

I have began the proof by showing that it holds for $n = 2$, and have assumed it holds for $n  \le  k$ for some arbitrary $k$. Now it just comes to showing that it holds for $k + 1$:

\begin{align}
\Pr\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{k+1} A_i\right) &= \Pr\left(A_{k+1} \cup \bigcup_{i=1}^kA_i\right)  \\
  &= \Pr(A_{k+1}) + \Pr\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^k A_i\right) - \Pr\left(A_{k+1} \cap \bigcup_{i=1}^kA_i\right)
\end{align}

where the last term can be written as:

$$
\Pr\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^k(A_i \cap A_{k+1})\right)
$$

This is where I am stuck and cannot simplify the expression to get the desired result. I am positive I am on the right track with the "proof", but do not know what result or axiom to use to continue

Any hints to how I can continue will be appreciated.

Comment: Remember that you want to prove it for $k+1$ assuming the $k$ case is true. Assuming the $k$ case is true, you can expand out $P(\bigcup_{i=1}^k X_i)$ for *any* collection of $k$ sets $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_k$. The second and third terms on the RHS of your second equation are unions of $k$ sets, so you can now expand them.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Did @Sebastian's answer help you? If so, please consider upvoting or accepting the answer. This is done by clicking the upwards normal distribution & possibly clicking on the check mark below the vote total. If it isn't quite what you needed, consider leaving a comment below his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use that you already proved the result for $n <k+1$.

Therefore $$P(\cup_{i=1}^k(A_{k+1}\cap A_i))=\sum_{i=1}^k P(A_{k+1}\cap A_i)-\sum_{i<j}^k P((A_{k+1}\cap A_i)\cap(A_{k+1}\cap A_j))- \sum_{i<j<l}^kP((A_{k+1}\cap A_i)\cap (A_{k+1} \cap A_j) \cap (A_{k+1} \cap A_l))- ... - (-1)^k((A_{k+1}\cap A_1)\cap...\cap(A_{k+1} \cap A_k))$$